# Does setting http response to blank identifier cause file handler leak?

Tags: go

Does this

```
_, myError := hc.Do(req)
```

cause file handler leak?

I don't see response getting closed in the [doc](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=17323:17375#L498) all the time, is the client responsible for closing the response even if its not using it?

Comment: How to handle this is explicitly documented in the same file you reference, [only a few lines above](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=17323:17375#L480): *"If the returned error is nil, the Response will contain a non-nil
Body __which the user is expected to close__."*

Comment: yeah, I was expecting some compiler magic to close it, that make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this causes a resource leak, preventing the underlying RoundTripper from reusing a persistent (keep-alive) connection.

From the source of `http.Response`;

> It is the caller's responsibility to close Body. 
>   The default HTTP client's Transport may not reuse HTTP/1.x "keep-alive" TCP connections if the Body is not read to completion and closed.

Assigning to the blank identifier doesn't change anything. You are still not reading or closing the `http.Response.Body`.